# How to delay the calling of render function until useEffect calls in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I want to run the `useEffect` first before the `render` function which is placed inside the `<Route/>` tag starts to render. I expect to get currently available user details through the API and assigne them to render function.

But render function runs before the `useEffect` retrieve data from the API. So help me to find the solution.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { getUser, setUser } from "../redux/userSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const User = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(async () => {
    await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({})
      .then((user) => {
        dispatch(setUser(user));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

 
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        User ? (
          ( children)
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/create-profile",
              state: { from: location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
 
};
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: You can't. Fetching data takes time, so you need to display something to the user in the meantime. Normally you show some kind of loading indicator, or you can stay on the previous screen if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delay the render as the execution of `useEffect`'s callback and updating a state are asynchronous tasks. The workaround is really simple though. You could use a `checking` state and show a loader while the data is being fetched. For that do so:

1. Create a state, I called it `checking` in `ProtectedRoute`:

> ```
> const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true);
> ```

2. Before that `retrun` you have add this:

> ```
> if (checking) return <p>Checking...</p>
> ```

3. Inside that `then` callback just after `dispatch(setUser(user))`, add this:

> ```
> setChecking(true)
> ```