# Fetch API does not fire at its position, though async await method is used

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, syntax-error, use-effect

I am stuck on a problem for last few day. Let me explain the problem. I am just learning the react and Django rest framework. So as a first project, I have chosen todo application with JWT authentication. On the frontend part of the project, on of my function is not working properly.

I made a function call `getTokenFromRefreshToken` to fetch the access when it is expires token through the saved refresh token as a cookie.

The function is something like this :

```
const getTokenFromRefreshToken = async (token) => {
    console.log("getTokenFromRefreshToken starts.");
    console.log("the token to refetch is : " + token);
    console.log("refetch the token");

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: `{"refresh":"${token}"}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log("We get the response from getTokenFromRefreshToken");
            console.log("Set the token variable");
            setToken(response.access);
            console.log("Set the refreshToken variable");
            setRefreshToken(response.refresh);
            console.log("Set the token cookie");
            setCookie('token', response.access);
            console.log("Set the refreshToken variable");
            setCookie('refreshToken', response.refresh);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
      console.log("getTokenFromRefreshToken ends.");
}
```

Now when I call the function it does not complete itself after `console.log("refetch the token");` this line and finally it is completed after all the other process completed and all the components are rendered.

That's why my `token` and `refreshToken` variables can not be updated so that when I am trying to make call on server for other data, I can not pass the token because it is invalid. Please help me.

There is other code :

useEffect of Main App component :

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("App component UseEffect Starts");

    if (cookies.previousLogin === "true") {
        console.log("we found previouslogin cookie is true. Now set the userAuthenticatedStatus variable value true.");
        setuserAuthenticatedStatus(true);

        if (cookies.token === undefined) {
            console.log("cookies.token is now undefined");
            console.log("Lets check about the refresh token");
            if (cookies.refreshToken === undefined) {
                console.log("There is also cookies.refreshToken is undefined");
            }
            else {
                console.log("The refresh token in cookie is : ");
                console.log(cookies.refreshToken);
                console.log("So we found cookies.refreshToken now we set the refreshToken variable with cookies.refreshToken");
                setRefreshToken(cookies.refreshToken);
                console.log("Now we need to get the token again using refresh token.");
                getTokenFromRefreshToken(cookies.refreshToken);
                console.log("Token is reloaded from refresh token");
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("The token in cookie is : ");
            console.log(cookies.token);
            console.log("So we found cookies.token now we set the token variable with cookies.token");
            setToken(cookies.token);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("You have not registed or login yet. Please login again.");
    }

    console.log("App component UseEffect ends");
}, []);
```

Here is my github repo link for your help.
link : https://github.com/rahulcodepython/todo_full_stackapp

Comment: First, try not to use `await` and `then` together that's anti pattern. To not change your code that much, remove that `await` before `fetch` and that `async` while defining your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delay the calling of render function until useEffect calls in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72984250/15288641)

Comment: I assume your JSX is being rendered before the request to the backend is finished, which is normal as it's an asynchronous task. See the answer given in the tread I pasted.